# After installing texlive2020 the old version is persisting

Tags: installing

I uninstalled and removed texlive 2017 by using the following commands in the terminal:

```
`sudo apt-get remove texlive
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get remove tex-common`
```

When typing in `pdflatex --version` in the terminal, I got command not found. I then installed texlive 2020 after downloading  `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` from `tug.org` webpage. I put everything needed under the PATH variable as recommended at the end of the installation. When I check for the version of latex in the terminal (I am using Ubuntu 18.04), I get the old version texlive 2017. I wanted to install the new version of texlive, since I was getting regularly error messages in TexStudio, which I could not handle otherwise. Do you have any idea why texlive2020 is not showing up ?

Comment: we can not tell what is wrong as what you describe is clearly not exactly as it is. If you removed texlive 2017 and haven't re-installed it then you could not get texlive 17 now.  what does `type pdflatex` or `which pdflatex`  report on the cmmandline, and what log do you get for `pdflatex small2e` ?

Comment: After checking with `which pdflatex`, I get `/usr/bin/pdflatex`, whereas `pdflatex small2e` results in a longer output, the first line being, `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
`.

Comment: the one in /usr/bin is the ubuntu supplied one not the one you installed from tug put /usr/local/texlive/2020/something/bin at the front of your path so you pick up the tug texlive 2020 (assuming you installed it in the default place)

Comment: there is no need to unstall the debian tex (unless you need the disk space)  and leaving it there simplifies some things as other debian packages then know tex is installed.

Comment: Thanks. I had already put the following line in path: `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux"`.  This is the only latex referring path in the `.bashrc` file. I also put the `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH` inside the path. I then sourced this file, `source .bashrc`. What should I do next ?

Comment: No that is wrong and does nothing, you put the new tex at the _end_ of your PATH so you pick up the existing one. Put it at the _start_ of your PATH.

Comment: so most likely if you use `type --all pdflatex` it will show you both versions of pdflatex, but the old one in /usr/bin is first and will be the one used.

Comment: I do not get it. By start of the PATH, do you mean beginning of the `.bashrc` file, i.e. the top of the file ?

Comment: PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH not PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux

Comment: Many thanks. It solved the issues. When it comes to TexStudio, will it automatically pick the 2020 version or not necessarily given that 2 texlive versions are present ?

Comment: no if the editor configuration just specifies "pdflatex" it will use the path so whichever is first. Of course if the editor specified pdflatex by its full path that will be used whatever PATH setting

Comment: In my case, the editor specifies only "pdflatex", I guess this is ok after the path change. I am also curious to know, why when I type in `type --all pdflatex` in the terminal, I get 3 copies of the 2020 version ? They are ordered as the 1st, 3d and the 4th entries, the 2nd one being the ubuntu supplied one. I only know that I tried many times today to install it. After it failed, I deleted what was installed so far as recommended at the tug.org webpage.

Comment: that's odd, but hard to debug from here

Comment: Make sure the path change is also in `.profile` and log out and in afterwards. Editors never sees anything bash related unless started from the commandline